# keyboard hide my textfield and my solution code didn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard, cgaffinetransform

Hello there are many questions about keyboard hide textfield problem

I saw many solutions between simple one and little bit complex one

I tried to move up my view by `origin.y`

when keyboard show

```
self.view.frame.origin.y = -150
```

keyboard hide

```
self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
```

sometimes it works but not now

when keyboard show, view moves up but it has black area when it downs like this

keyboard shows up

[image]

keyboard down

[image]

of course it occurs in my real device what's the problem?

so i use `CGAffineTransform` like this, **and it works!**

```
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification){
    self.view.transform = .identity
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification){
    guard let userInfo = sender.userInfo as? [String:Any] else {return}
    guard let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height + 60)
}
```

is it fine? or has potential error?

Answer (score 0):

This will not hide your keyboard.You can scroll the textfield when keyboard appears, Just -

> Make a `UIScrollView` in your Storyboard

And write this code in your `ViewController` -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    //MARK: - // left it as it is, don't make it's connection with storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var activeTextField: UITextField? 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.setNotificationKeyboard()
    }

    // Notification when keyboard show
    func setNotificationKeyboard ()  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    //MARK: - get current text field
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField;
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = nil
    }
    //MARK: - when show keyboard increase height of scroll view
    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height+10, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeTextField
        {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    //MARK: - when keyboard hide reduce height of scroll view
    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating UIViewController's base view is not a good idea. You can and most likely will run into some wierd issues.

I recommend that you embed everything that needs to be moved into it's own UIView: Select all subviews, **Editor -> Embed -> View**. Add all required constraints and create an IBOutlet for the bottom constraint - **inputViewBottomConstraint**.

Then in your view controller add this:

```
fileprivate func subscribeToNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
        self?.updateInputViewConstraints(withUserInfo: notification.userInfo, isAppearing: true)
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
        self?.updateInputViewConstraints(withUserInfo: notification.userInfo, isAppearing: false)
    }
}

fileprivate func updateInputViewConstraints(withUserInfo userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]?, isAppearing: Bool) {
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let animationCurve: UIViewAnimationOptions = {
        let curve = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        return UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve)
    }()
    inputViewBottomConstraint.constant = isAppearing ? keyboardFrame.size.height : 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good library to manage keyboard in iOS apps
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

You should use this library.

Answer (score 0):

> Since part of your screen is getting hidden behind the keyboard, you
>   can use a Scroll View - the user will then be able to scroll up and
>   down to access the whole screen.

In your xib or Storyboard file, add a UIScrollView. Assuming you already have elements added, a quick way to do this will be -

1. Select all the elements on the screen you want to put inside the
   scrollable area. From top bar in XCode, select Editor -> Embed In
   -> View. You can rename this view as ContentView.
2. Select the ContentView and now from top bar in XCode, select Editor -> Embed In
   -> Scroll View
3. For the Scroll View, set top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to 0 (from the Superview/Safe Area whichever
   you are using).
4. For the ContentView, set top, bottom, left and
   right margins to 0, also set center horizontally and vertically (all from the scrollView as it is the superView).
5. Now you can add
   all your views in that ContentView, and the contentSize of the
   scrollView will be automatically resized accordingly. For your case - Adjust rest of the constraints on your
   screen accordingly. Say, by giving the vertical spacing of the top
   most element of screen with the Content View (Similar process for
   the bottom most element). This step is same as designing any UI
   screen in iOS.
6. You can optionally do this step to dismiss the
   scrollView when user starts scrolling. Select the Scroll View, tap
   on Attributes Inspector and set Keyboard option to "Dismiss on
   drag".

> If you still want to move the UI elements based on whether keyboard is
>   present/shown or hidden. Then, you can move the content View's
>   position from the Scroll View by setting scrollView's
>   [setContentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset) property.

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    func addKeyboardNotifications() {             
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SampleViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SampleViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
            // This will move the contentView upwards by the same amount as the height of the keyboard which appears on screen
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: keyboardHeight), animated: true)
         }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // This will move the contentView back to it's original position.
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)